# data from useQuery mutates when shouldn't

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I'm fetching data from a DB using useQuery. like this:

```
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import axios from "axios";

const useGetExpenses = () =>
  useQuery({
    queryKey: ["getExpenses"],
    queryFn: async () => {
      const res = await axios.get("/expenses/");
      return res.data;
    },
    enabled: axios.defaults.headers.Authorization ? true : false,
  });

export default useGetExpenses;
```

then, I'm filtering the data by month and finally rendering it to a table by using useState
like this:

```
const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);
  // rows starts as an empty array and is mutated to either be an array of objects as fetched from the DB,
  // or an array of objects from an empty template. this is determined in useGetMonthlyExpensesOrTemplate.

  const { data: expenses } = useGetExpenses();
  // retrieves ALL expenses from DB made by connected user, but NOT filtered by month

  const filtredByMonthExpensesOrTemplate = useGetMonthlyExpensesOrTemplate(
    props.monthIndexSelected
  );
  // this hooks returns an array either of  selected month's expenses,
  // or, if none are submitted, of a template empty entries

  useEffect(() => {
    // this effect mutates 'rows' when first mounted
    // and whenever the user selects a different month (on the parent component's month selector)
    // or whenever the value of expenses is mutated.
    setRows(filtredByMonthExpensesOrTemplate);
  }, [props.monthIndexSelected, expenses]);
```

however, when a user makes changes to rows (the array rendered out in the interactive table) it modifies filtredByMonthExpensesOrTemplate as well for some reason.

why so and how can I avoid that?

Comment: I don't see you ever use `expenses`. Try replacing `setRows(filtredByMonthExpensesOrTemplate)` with `setRows([...filtredByMonthExpensesOrTemplate])`

Comment: thanks @Konrad. it doesn't makes a difference... expenses is used within the hook useGetMonthlyExpensesOrTemplate. I can't put it here in the comment because it's too long

Comment: please provide details on how the user updates the rows

Comment: @Anton, onchange: newRows = [...rows]; newRows[i].someField = e.target.value; setRows(newRows)

Answer (score 0):

When you do `newRows = [ ...rows ]`, you do create a new array, however, the elements in the array are the same. That means that when you change an element in the array, this element will change for other arrays too. What you do want to do is to create a *new* element with the updated data.

Here's two suggestions for how to do this. I would prefer the second as it does not mutate the array `newRows`.

```js
const newRows = [ ...rows ];
// create the new element
const newElement = {
  // take all data from the old element
  ...rows[i],
  // set a new value for the field someField
  someField: e.target.value,
};
// add the element to the list
newRows[i] = newElement;
```

```js
const newRows = [
  // take all elements before the new element
  ...rows.slice(0, i),
  // create the new element
  {
    // take all data from the old element
    ...rows[i],
    // set a new value for the field someField
    someField: e.target.value,
  },
  // take all elements after the new element
  ...rows.slice(i + 1),
];
```

Answer (score -2):

I've changes my GET request of expenses to a simple axios request instead of using reactQuery and the issue was solved. So I can assume the issue has to do with useQuery. If anyone has an idea what was the issue and how to solve it while still using reactQuery I'd be glad to know